Is putting capacitors in both ESP32 and HX711 overkill in this circuit?
I was getting erratic readings from my HX711, which was receiving power supply from my ESP32. I figured it was catching noise and power fluctuations from my ESP32.

So I added a 0.1 μF capacitor and a 10 μF capacitor to the VVcc and GND pins of my HX711 and ESP32. The readings have been perfect so far.
Is this overkill? Maybe I just needed to add the capactiors to the HX711?

Please understand you don't have an "ESP32" and "HX711" as they are chips. What you have is ready made modules with these chips, and with hopefully enough capacitors on them, and you can't really know anything about these modules unless you are given some documentation or manual how they work and if they require any external capacitanve. We also don't know how you wired the modules together so if it is correct or not. Regarding how they are powered that is. Also a radio transmitter like the ESP32 near a sensitive load cell sensor is just asking for trouble unless the system is well designed.

”I figured it was catching noise and power fluctuations from my ESP32” Measure with your oscilloscope and post results.

If the HX711 works with the capacitors but not without them, then clearly they were necessary. If the ESP32 worked without them then perhaps they are overkill but if they're not causing problems then they're not harming anything. It doesn't look like you're designing for a high-volume production run where every penny on the BOM counts. A good (e.g. star) grounding configuration can also help with reducing undesirable interactions between components that may couple through the supply rails.
Another aspect to consider is the (desirable) damping effect a higher-ESR cap like an electrolytic has on the supply overshoot a long supply lead can create on the positive voltage rail.
